# Unable to login to psql with a newly defined user

Tags: postgresql, authentication, terminal, psql

I'm trying to connect to psql with my newly created user but unfortunately I'm no able to.

Here's the error message that I got.
[image]

Here's the list of my users, as shown in the image there is a user named `pxsa`.
[image]

So I can't figure it out!

I can login with the user `postgres` with no difficulty.
[image]

Comment: You appear to be confusing operating-system users with postgresql users. They are two separate lists and only sometimes match up.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, can you give me a clue?

Comment: `psql -U pxsa -d postgres`. This assumes that [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) will allow it.